# Formatting strings to tabulature format in Python

Tags: python, string, streamlit

I have a lot of strings like `'---\n---\n---\n-0-'` and `'---\n---\n-3-\n---'`, and I want to print them *side by side* like this:

> ```
> ------
> ------
> ----3-
> -0----
> ```

How to do this?

Here is my code:

```
def formating_list_to_tab(note_list):
    if 'E_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n---\n-0-'
    elif 'F_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n---\n-1-'
    elif 'F#_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n---\n-2-'
    elif 'G_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n---\n-3-'
    elif 'G#_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n---\n-4-'
    elif 'A_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n---\n-5-'
    elif 'A#_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n-1-\n---'
    elif 'B_0' in note_list:
        return '---\n---\n-2-\n---'

def print_tab():
    note_list = []
    for item in notes:
        freq = detect_peak(*get_note_freq(item))
        note_list.append(recognize_note(freq))
    return note_list

note_array = print_tab()

opening_tab = 'G\nD\nA\nE'

for note in note_array:
    
    note_into_tab = formating_list_to_tab(note)
    opening_tab += note_into_tab

st.text(opening_tab)
```

Here is my result:

> ```
> G  
> D 
> A 
> E---
> ---
> ---
> -2----
> ---
> ---
> -5----
> ---
> ---
> -0----
> ---
> ---
> -0----
> ---
> ---
> -2----
> ---
> ---
> -0----
> ---
> ---
> -0-
> ```

Sorry in advance for bad English and thank you for loosing time on me =)
And stackoverflow system asks me to make more details. To show string values i'm using streamlit library.

Comment: If you have literally `s = '---\n---\n---\n-0-'`, then you just need to `print(s)`. Otherwise you need to be clearer about what exactly you have, preferably with clear code samples, since otherwise it's not clear what exactly we're supposedly looking at.

Comment: `opening_tab += note_into_tab` — You'll want to add another `'\n'` between the strings you're concatenating here.

Comment: Sorry deceze, i'm new user in this forum. I updated my question with code.

Comment: @deceze in whath place i must put '\n'? this operator makes new line, but it's already getting new lines in the function

Comment: You have one string that ends with `..-`, and the next begins with `-..`. If you concatenate them both together you get `..--..`, which is not what you want. You want `..-\n-..`. So something like `opening_tab += '\n' + note_into_tab`.

Comment: it does not work for me =( i need every 4 lines getting in line, like i show in the first part of question

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic then. Take *out* some newlines then?!

Comment: sorry for my english, maybe its cause problems with understanding. i need to show all chunks with 4 strings in ONE line, horizontally. but my actual result is, that every chunk printing on the new line. thats problem

Comment: You want to display two such strings *side by side*?

Comment: yes, exactly!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant append to an earlier line, you need to build a string for each line separately, then print those in order

```py
def formating_list_to_tab(note_list):
    # returns list of strings, one for each line
    if 'E_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','---','-0-'
    elif 'F_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','---','-1-'
    elif 'F#_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','---','-2-'
    elif 'G_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','---','-3-'
    elif 'G#_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','---','-4-'
    elif 'A_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','---','-5-'
    elif 'A#_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','-1-','---'
    elif 'B_0' in note_list:
        return '---','---','-2-','---'

def print_tab():
    note_list = []
    for item in notes:
        freq = detect_peak(*get_note_freq(item))
        note_list.append(recognize_note(freq))
    return note_list

note_array = print_tab()

g_line = 'G'
d_line = 'D'
a_line = 'A'
e_line = 'E'

for note in note_array:
    # unpack list from function for each line
    g_note,d_note,a_note,e_note = formating_list_to_tab(note)
    g_line += g_note
    d_line += d_note
    a_line += a_note
    e_line += e_note

# print each line
st.text(g_line + '\n' + d_line + '\n' + a_line + '\n' + e_line + '\n')
```

Comment: it give me error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)"

Comment: i made mistake, now it works, thank you very much!!!!